# Getting Syntax Error on INSERT INTO command on Visual Basic 2010 to MS ACCESS 2007

Tags: database, vb.net, insert, ms-access-2007

I keep getting a syntax error when I run a debug on the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles add.Click
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'Open Connection if not yet Open
        cnn.Open()  End If
    cmd.Connection = cnn

    If Me.sn.Tag & "" = "" Then            
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO First_Year(Student_No,Lastname,Firstname,Year_Level,Enroll_Date,SEX,SY,CIVIL_STATUS,Religion,Birthdate,TEL_NO,Father,Occupation_F,Mother,Occupation_m,School Last Attended,Address School,Middle_Name)" +
                          "VALUES ('" & Me.sn.Text & "','" & Me.fn.Text & "','" & Me.ln.Text & "' ,'" & Me.Year.Text & "','" & Me.ed.Value & "','" & Me.s.Text & "','" & Me.sy.Text & "','" & Me.cs.Text & "','" & Me.re.Text & "'," & Me.cn.Text & ",'" & Me.bd.Value & "','" & Me.fa.Text & "','" & Me.fo.Text & "','" & Me.ma.Text & "','" & Me.mo.Text & "','" & Me.lad.Text & "','" & Me.ad.Text & "','" & Me.mi.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Can some please point out to me whats wrong with it?

Comment: Could you also please include either a screenshot or verbatim write up of the error message that you're getting please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some fields name that contains spaces. To use these fields names you need to enclose them in square brackets

```
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO First_Year " & _
            "(Student_No,Lastname,Firstname,Year_Level,Enroll_Date,SEX, " & _
            "SY,CIVIL_STATUS,Religion,Birthdate,TEL_NO,Father,Occupation_F,Mother, " & 
            "Occupation_m,[School Last Attended],[Address School],Middle_Name) " & 
            "...... "
```

Said that, remember that string concatenations like yours lead to Sql Injection and problem in parsing strings that contains quotes (O'Brien) or decimal numbers or date

Search about [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and [Parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

A parameterized approach to your query would be

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO First_Year " & _
        "(Student_No,Lastname,Firstname,Year_Level,Enroll_Date,SEX, " & _
        "SY,CIVIL_STATUS,Religion,Birthdate,TEL_NO,Father,Occupation_F,Mother, " & 
        "Occupation_m,[School Last Attended],[Address School],Middle_Name) " & 
        "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Me.sn.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Me.fn.Text)
... and so on for the remainder 16 parameters placeholders 
... respecting their position and converting to the appropriate datatype
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the space here (in your query) :

```
......School Last Attended,Address School.......
```

or write it like this :

```
..........[School Last Attended],[Address School]..........
```